# Edit attribute values of XML using VB6

Tags: xml, vb6

I need to update the attribute value of bkp_path using VB6.

### XML File

```
<ServerDetails>
    <Param src_path = "D:\Shapes\Rectangle" bkp_path = "D:\Colors\Red"/>
</ServerDetails>
```

I'm able to read values from XML file using

### VB6 Code

```
Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim success As Boolean
'Load Config.xml
success = doc.Load("\Config\config.xml")

If success = False Then
  MsgBox ("Unable to locate the configuration file")
  Exit Function
Else
  Dim nodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

  Set nodeList = doc.selectNodes("/ServerDetails/Param")

  If Not nodeList Is Nothing Then
     Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

     For Each node In nodeList
        srcpath = node.selectSingleNode("@src_path").Text
        bkpPath = node.selectSingleNode("@bkp_path").Text            
     Next node
  End If
End If
```

but can't figure out how to update attribute values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick :

`node.selectSingleNode("@bkp_path").Text = "D:\Colors\Blue"`

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a reference to the node object then call `setAttribute()` to specify the new value:

```
node.setAttribute "bkp_path", "wibble"
```

Your code also reads the values from all the `Param` nodes but you may want to only use the first or update a specific one.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to update a particular attribute not the first one, in this case 'bkp_path'. I've tried this earlier as well, didnt work.

Comment: I said node (`<Param ...>`), not the attribute (`src_path =`). The attributes (using this code) are referenced by name. The code you supplied reads the values from EVERY `<Param>` node, but I assume you only want to set one of them.

Comment: Yes, it should read each `<Param>` and update each `bkp_path` attribute.
Finally, found the solution. 
This is what I was looking for :
`node.selectSingleNode("@bkp_path").Text = "D:\Colors\Blue"`

Anyways thank you for the prompt replies.

Comment: Which does the same as I suggested... If you've found your answer, [please post it as an answer and accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).